# Efficient (fastest) way to sum elements of matrix in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, sum

Lets have matrix `A` say `A = magic(100);`. I have seen 2 ways of computing sum of all elements of matrix `A`.

```
sumOfA = sum(sum(A));
```

Or

```
sumOfA = sum(A(:));
```

Is one of them faster (or better practise) then other? If so which one is it? Or are they both equally fast?

Comment: Every method must walk through every element of the matrix. So they are just the same when it comes to complexity. I would recommend you to make two scripts with the different methods, huge matrices, and compute their execution time. Taking a long shot here, I would say the second is better, since it do not involves memory alloc operations, but like I said, its a long shot and I may be missing something here.

Comment: You could use Matlab's `tic` and `toc` functions to perform the experiment.

Comment: I did a quick test and there was no difference in speed.  An advantage of `sum(A(:))` is that you don't need to know how many dimensions `A` has; it will work for any number of dims.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that you can't make up your mind about whether performance or floating point accuracy is more important.

If floating point accuracy were of paramount accuracy, then you would segregate the positive and negative elements, sorting each segment. Then sum in order of increasing absolute value. Yeah, I know, its more work than anyone would do, and it probably will be a waste of time.

Instead, use adequate precision such that any errors made will be irrelevant. Use good numerical practices about tests, etc, such that there are no problems generated.

As far as the time goes, for an NxM array,

sum(A(:)) will require N*M-1 additions.

sum(sum(A)) will require (N-1)*M + M-1 = N*M-1 additions.

Either method requires the same number of adds, so for a large array, even if the interpreter is not smart enough to recognize that they are both the same op, who cares?

It is simply not an issue. Don't make a mountain out of a mole hill to worry about this.

Edit: in response to Amro's comment about the errors for one method over the other, there is little you can control. The additions will be done in a different order, but there is no assurance about which sequence will be better.

```
A = randn(1000);
format long g
```

The two solutions are quite close. In fact, compared to eps, the difference is barely significant.

```
sum(A(:))
ans =
          945.760668102446

sum(sum(A))
ans =
          945.760668102449

sum(sum(A)) - sum(A(:))
ans =
      2.72848410531878e-12

eps(sum(A(:)))
ans =
      1.13686837721616e-13
```

Suppose you choose the segregate and sort trick I mentioned. See that the negative and positive parts will be large enough that there will be a loss of precision.

```
sum(sort(A(A<0),'descend'))
ans =
          -398276.24754782

sum(sort(A(A<0),'descend')) + sum(sort(A(A>=0),'ascend'))
ans =
            945.7606681037
```

So you really would need to accumulate the pieces in a higher precision array anyway. We might try this:

```
[~,tags] = sort(abs(A(:)));
sum(A(tags))
ans =
          945.760668102446
```

An interesting problem arises even in these tests. Will there be an issue because the tests are done on a random (normal) array? Essentially, we can view sum(A(:)) as a random walk, a drunkard's walk. But consider sum(sum(A)). Each element of sum(A) (i.e., the internal sum) is itself a sum of 1000 normal deviates. Look at a few of them:

```
sum(A)
ans =
  Columns 1 through 6
         -32.6319600960983          36.8984589766173          38.2749084367497          27.3297721091922          30.5600109446534          -59.039228262402
  Columns 7 through 12
          3.82231962760523          4.11017616179294         -68.1497901792032          35.4196443983385          7.05786623564426         -27.1215387236418
  Columns 13 through 18
```

When we add them up, there will be a loss of precision. So potentially, the operation as sum(A(:)) might be slightly more accurate. Is it so? What if we use a higher precision for the accumulation? So first, I'll form the sum down the columns using doubles, then convert to 25 digits of decimal precision, and sum the rows. (I've displayed only 20 digits here, leaving 5 digits hidden as guard digits.)

```
sum(hpf(sum(A)))
ans =
945.76066810244807408
```

Or, instead, convert immediately to 25 digits of precision, then summing the result.

```
sum(hpf(A(:))
945.76066810244749807
```

So both forms in double precision were equally wrong here, in opposite directions. In the end, this is all moot, since any of the alternatives I've shown are far more time consuming compared to the simple variations sum(A(:)) or sum(sum(A)). Just pick one of them and don't worry.

Comment: Thanks you, great answer. This is why I asked this question: I have 2 pieces of code that both do the same think (always produce same result). But one of runs twice as long as the other. There are very few differences between them and the way they sum matrixes was one of them. It was my guess that it could be the part that makes the performance difference. I'l have to look somewhere else. Performance is so important here because it is optimization problem on large data... And I'd rather wait 1 day for result then 2 days.

Comment: @drasto Have you tried profiling your code? You say you have "very few differences between them", with this being only one. Have you looked at others? I'd be very surprised, nay, aghast if the "bottleneck" in an "optimization problem on large data" was the summing of the elements of a matrix.

Comment: One concern I would have with `sum(sum(A))` is if the interpreter  decides to allocate a temporary matrix to hold the result of the inner `sum`.  If you're doing this in the middle of a loop, and you have a very large number of columns, allocating and freeing that temporary matrix could turn into a real performance drag.  It's possible that the Matlab JIT can optimize this away, but I've seen kind of similar situations where it didn't.

Comment: @woodchips: +1 great answer as always. @sfstewman: `sum(A(:))` also creates a temp linearized matrix/vector before performing the outer sum

Comment: @Amro: The temp matrix created by `A(:)` should be copy-on-write optimized.  Matlab will allocate the overhead for a matrix (which is a few bytes), but should reuse the data.  In contrast, the inner sum of `sum(sum(A(:)))` takes an MxN matrix and generates an 1xN matrix.  If the JIT doesn't optimize this correctly, that requires a 1xN matrix to be allocated.  There's no copy-on-write optimization available.

Comment: @sstewman: somehow I though that `A(:)` forces MATLAB to make a "real" copy, but you are right. I just tested it using `format debug` with `B=A` vs `B=A(:)`, both had the same address in memory as `A`. I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 3):

Performance-wise, I'd say both are very similar (assuming a recent MATLAB version). Here is quick test using the [TIMEIT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function) function:

```
function sumTest()
    M = randn(5000);
    timeit( @() func1(M) )
    timeit( @() func2(M) )
end
function v = func1(A)
    v = sum(A(:));
end
function v = func2(A)
    v = sum(sum(A));
end
```

the results were:

```
>> sumTest
ans =
    0.0020917
ans =
    0.0017159
```

What I would worry about is floating-point issues. Example:

```
>> M = randn(1000);
>> abs( sum(M(:)) - sum(sum(M)) )
ans =
   3.9108e-11
```

Error magnitude increases for larger matrices

Comment: So speaking about floating-point issues which method is preferable?

Comment: There is NO way to know which one will give a better answer. The two results will be completely random in the lower order bits. It all depends on what order the numbers are added in, which is something that neither matlab or you will worry about.

Answer (score 0):

i think a simple way to understand is apply " **tic_ toc** "function in first and last of your code.

```
tic
A = randn(5000);
format long g
sum(A(:));
toc
```

but when you used randn function ,elements of it are random and time of calculation can 
different in each cycle **CPU** calculation . 
This better you used a unique matrix whit so large elements to compare time of calculation.